# Teradata regular expressions

Tags: regex, teradata

How can I delete everything that appears after the second bar?

```
SELECT REGEXP_replace('/admin/home/log', '(/\w+){,2}','');
SELECT REGEXP_replace('/admin/home/out', '(/\w+){,2}','');
SELECT REGEXP_replace('/admin/login', '(/\w+){,2}','');
SELECT REGEXP_replace('/test/login', '(/\w+){,2}','');
SELECT REGEXP_replace('/test/login/file/cam', '(/\w+){,2}','');
```

Solutions:

```
/admin/home
/admin/home
/admin/login
/test/login
/test/login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regexp_replace()`:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/admin/home/log/test', '([^/]/[^/]*/).*$', '\1');
```

Comment: The STRTOK option will misbehave if the string doesn't have at least 2 slashes - it will end up adding a slash at the end, oddly enough. `SELECT STRTOK('/test/login', '/', 1) || '/' || STRTOK('/test/login', '/', 2) || '/';` returns `test/login/`. You're also losing the first slash. Regex is perfect though.

Comment: strtok is so picky. I will remove.

Comment: What is the third argument (`'\1'`) doing? Isn't that the replacement string?

Comment: The `([^/]/[^/]*/)` is a capture group looking for a string that 1) doesn't contain a slash 2) followed by a slash 3)followed by a string without a slash 4) follwed by a slash. Then the `.*$` is everything after that until the end. It replaces what was matched (everything) with the first (and only) capture group: `/1`. Perhaps there is a prettier way, but it's 4pm here and my brain is shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

Instead if replacing the remainder you can simply extract everything before a 3rd slash:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('/admin/home/log', '(/[^/]+){1,2}');
```